# Waiting for a element to load using watir

Tags: ruby, watir, ruby-1.9.3

I just migrated to ruby 1.9.3 from 1.8.. Instead of using the wait methods I had a method of my own that used to check for a element to load and it used to work perfectly on 1.8.7. But after I upgraded to ruby 1.9.3 the method fails at random times with the below exception.

> unknown property or method: `parentelement'
>       HRESULT error code:0x80070005
>         Access is denied.
>       C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-2.0.4/lib/watir/element.rb:168:in`method_missing'
>       C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-2.0.4/lib/watir/element.rb:168:in `parent'
>       D:/Ruby_193/Watir/script/script1.rb:78:in`block (2 levels) in test_script1'
>       D:/Ruby_193/Watir/lib/helper.rb:494:in `call'
>       D:/Ruby_193/Watir/lib/helper.rb:494:in`load_finished'
>       D:/Ruby_193/Watir/lib/helper.rb:488:in `wait_for_pageload'
>       D:/Ruby_193/Watir/script/script1.rb:78:in`block in test_script1'
>       D:/Ruby_193/Watir/lib/helper.rb:526:in `call'
>       D:/Ruby_193/Watir/lib/helper.rb:526:in`run_step'
>       D:/Ruby_193/Watir/script/script1.rb:71:in `test_script1'

The code at line no. 78 in my script1.rb is

```
77: browser.button(:value, "Generate").click
78: wait_for_pageload( lambda {browser.cell(:text,"Coversheet").parent.link(:text,"template").exists? })
```

which calls the wait_for_pageload method in the helper.rb file

```
482:def wait_for_pageload(page_lambda = nil, &page_closure)
483:  script = "window.frames.frame::1.document.enabled"
484:  page_lambda = page_closure if block_given?
485:  count = 0
486:  load_limit = 1200
487:  sleep_time = 0.1
488:  sleep sleep_time until load_finished(script, page_lambda) || (count +=1) > load_limit
489:  raise "Unable to load page in over #{load_limit} tries (#{sleep_time * load_limit} seconds)" if count > load_limit
490:end
```

the wait_for_pageload method in-turn calls the load_finished method and passes the javascript variable and the page_lambda to the method

```
493:def load_finished(script, page_lambda)
494:  page_lambda.nil? ? browser.execute_script(script).to_s == "true" : page_lambda.call()
495:end
private :load_finished
```

Sorry I will not be able to provide a link to the site or html.

What happens is when I click on the Generate button(line no 77.) the page refreshes and a template link is displayed. The time taken to display the template link varies each time. So I am checking if the link is displayed or not with the help of wait_for_pageload.

But after the link is generated when I run the below code it returns true.

```
browser.cell(:text,"Coversheet").parent.link(:text,"template").exists?
```

So I am sure its not an error with that part. I did a little research and found that there have been changes in proc and lambda in 1.9.3 and I guess the issue occurs at the line no. 494 `page_lambda.nil? ? browser.execute_script(script).to_s == "true" : page_lambda.call()`

I am clueless about what changes in 1.9.3 are causing this issue. It would be of great help if anyone can help me.

Comment: Based on the exception, I think it is failing on the `parent` call. Does the `browser.cell(:text,"Coversheet")` exist before the page refreshes or only after?

Comment: @JustinKo Thanks for you reply.. The text "Coversheet" is displayed before the page refresh itself. In my scenario the screen refreshes(more than once) in between until the template link is displayed. As mentioned in my question this piece of code used to work fine on ruby 1.8.7. I am getting this error only after upgrading.